# Transformar coluna de uma tabela em lista no Python

Tags: python, pandas

```
importances_DT = pd.DataFrame({'feature':x.columns,'importance':np.round(decision_tree.feature_importances_,3)})
importances_DT = importances_DT.sort_values('importance',ascending=False).set_index('feature')
```

Como consigo "pegar" só a coluna feature e colocar em uma lista?

Tentei a seguinte linha de código:

```
lista = importances_DT ["feature"].tolist()
```

Answer (score 3):

Patricia é exatamente como você tentou fazer.
Veja o exemplo abaixo, e caso queira testa-lo pode acessar [aqui](https://repl.it/@MuriloPortugal/Python-testes).

```
import pandas as pd

dados = {'feature': [1, 2], 'importance': [3, 4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dados)
df.sort_values('importance',ascending=False).set_index('feature')

lista = df['feature'].tolist()

print(lista)
for item in lista:
  print(item)
```